# Php Redis connection issue

Tags: php, redis, iptables

I'm using php-redis as a session manger and I'm having a weird problem.

I run on one Centos 6.4 machine php and in another server I have redis, so everything works fine if I disable the firewall of the php machine.

But as soon as I start iptables, php-redis won't connect to the redis server.

I, of course have a rule, but obviously is not working:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT;
```

I have restarted iptables and checked correctly that the rule is applied. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is your Redis instance listen on port 6379?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

`iptables -N REDIS
iptables -A REDIS -s localhost -j ACCEPT
iptables -A REDIS -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A REDIS -j LOG --log-prefix "unauth-redis-access"
iptables -A REDIS -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 6379 -j REDIS`

https://serverfault.com/questions/532075/redis-no-route-to-host-when-pinging-a-remote-redis-host